# Can Graphics.DrawString give different width results on different computers?

Tags: winforms

I'm using Graphics.DrawString to draw a word inside a box. The boxes have a pre-defined minimum width which is large enough to accomodate the word.

Code:

```
                RectangleF behaviorRect = new RectangleF(bodyRect.Left + bodyRect.Width / 8,
                                         bodyRect.Top + bodyRect.Height / 8,
                                         bodyRect.Width * 3 / 4,
                                         bodyRect.Height * 3 / 4);
                g.DrawRectangle(bluePen, bodyRect.Left + bodyRect.Width / 8,
                                         bodyRect.Top + bodyRect.Height / 8,
                                         bodyRect.Width * 3 / 4,
                                         bodyRect.Height * 3 / 4);
                g.DrawString("Behavior", textFont, blueBrush, behaviorRect, centerFormat);
```

On every Windows system this application has been tried on, it works fine. But one guy's Win 7 laptop is wrapping the text. Any ideas about why it would do this? The font is Verdana, and it appears to be using the correct font in the image.

[image: Word is wrapping on one guy's computer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The person in question had set his fonts to render at +25% size in the control panel. So the short answer to my question is, "yes".